# A question about the module of differentials

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I want solve this good exercise:

> Let $(S,m)$ be a regular local ring that is the localization at a maximal ideal of a finitely generated algebra over a field $k$, and let $x_1, \ldots, x_d$ be a system of parameters. Show that if $S/m$ is a separable extension of $k$, then $\Omega_{S/k}$ is a free S-module of rank $d$ generated by the $dx_i$.

I think this is an application of "Conormal Sequence" but I don't know how use the separabitity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The left map in the conormal exact sequence is injective if $S/m $ is a separable extension of $k $. (See Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory*, Theorems 25.2 and 26.9.)